# NSInternalInconsistencyException: Firebase crashes SwiftUI app on launch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I am trying to add Firebase auth via Apple Sign-in and have got this error:

`` crashed due to an uncaught exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. Reason: The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App Delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI) ``

This is how I launch Firebase:

```swift
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

I did not install the Firebase package directly, but instead added [this package.](https://github.com/rebeloper/FirebaseService.git) which I believe added Firebase as one of its dependency. I have checked other solutions but they all rely on CocoaPods while I'm using the Swift Package Manager. Not sure how I can resolve this error.

App calling `AppDelegate`:

```
import FirebaseService
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SomeApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

  @State private var authState = AuthState()

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      switch authState.value {
      case .undefined:
        ProgressView()
      case .authenticated:
        ContentView()
      case .notAuthenticated:
        AuthView()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using SwiftUI, are you sure that the app delegate code you have shown is being called?  Do you have an `@UIApplicationDelegateAdapter(AppDelegate.self)` in your app struct?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have added the part where I am calling the App.

Comment: What does the `AuthState()` object do?  Does it access Firebase auth?

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that another part of your app tries to access Firebase Auth before Firebase is initialised in your your app delegate.

Looking at the code of [Rebeloper's package](https://github.com/rebeloper/FirebaseService) which you're using, we can see that it calls `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` in [line 16 of AuthListener](https://github.com/rebeloper/FirebaseService/blob/main/Sources/FirebaseService/AuthListener/AuthListener.swift#L16). Since you create an instance of [`AuthState`](https://github.com/rebeloper/FirebaseService/blob/main/Sources/FirebaseService/AuthState/AuthState.swift#L12) (another class from Rebeloper's library), this is executed *before* Firebase is initialised.

Instead of using an undocumented third party library, I would recommend implementing this yourself - especially since it's only a few lines of code.

To see how this is done, check out [Getting started with Firebase Auth for Apple platforms - Firebase Fundamentals](https://youtu.be/q-9lx7aSWcc), which not only explains Firebase Auth and how to handle authentication state in detail, but also includes the corresponding source code.

As an added bonus, this contains a beautiful signup/login form:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode with a login screen running in the iOS Simulator]

For reference, here is the source code for registering an authentication state listener in an `ObserableObject`:

```swift
@MainActor
class AuthenticationViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var email = ""
  @Published var password = ""
  @Published var confirmPassword = ""

  @Published var flow: AuthenticationFlow = .login

  @Published var isValid  = false
  @Published var authenticationState: AuthenticationState = .unauthenticated
  @Published var errorMessage = ""
  @Published var user: User?
  @Published var displayName = ""

  init() {
    registerAuthStateHandler()
    // ...
  }

  private var authStateHandler: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

  func registerAuthStateHandler() {
    if authStateHandler == nil {
      authStateHandler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        self.user = user
        self.authenticationState = user == nil ? .unauthenticated : .authenticated
        self.displayName = user?.email ?? ""
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will look into that. However, my understanding is that App Delegate runs before I call ```AuthState()```. Hence, firebase should be initialised there right?

Comment: The easiest way to find out is by setting a breakpoint on each of the lines.